# How do I get the pubkey for ksplice?

Tags: apt, software-installation, oracle, add-apt-repository

(I am aware that installing third-party bundles poses a theoretical security risk.)

I am using [ksplice](https://ksplice.oracle.com/try/desktop#:%7E:text=Double%2Dclick%20the%20uptrack.&text=Ubuntu%20Software%20Center%20will%20bring,and%20the%20installation%20will%20begin.&text=You%20will%20next%20be%20prompted,to%20Linux%2C%20all%20without%20rebooting.) to apply kernel updates for a running system. After installing, I cannot run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

anymore as it complaints:

```
Get:8 http://www.ksplice.com/apt focal InRelease [3.483 B]              
Err:8 http://www.ksplice.com/apt focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 82562EA9AD986DA3
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://www.ksplice.com/apt focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 82562EA9AD986DA3
E: The repository 'http://www.ksplice.com/apt focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It's to be expected, and I thought I could install the pubkey via:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 82562EA9AD986DA3
```

though that fails via:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

I am assuming I am using the wrong keyserver. I can't find any results when googling for the key hash and the [user guide](https://ksplice.oracle.com/uptrack/guide) also does not provide any hint on the key.

Where can I get the pubkey for ksplice?

---

NObert's proposed solutions does not work, it still complains:

```
$ cat ksplice-archive.asc 
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.6 (GNU/Linux)
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=8Hod
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
$ sudo apt-key add ksplice-archive.asc
OK

 $ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phoerious/keepassxc/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                 
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]                 
Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                         
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                            
Hit:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                       
Get:8 http://www.ksplice.com/apt focal InRelease [3.483 B]                         
Err:8 http://www.ksplice.com/apt focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 82562EA9AD986DA3
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://www.ksplice.com/apt focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 82562EA9AD986DA3
E: The repository 'http://www.ksplice.com/apt focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow Ubuntu documentation located at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ksplice and then use commands from it to get key added

> ```
> sudo wget -N https://www.ksplice.com/apt/ksplice-archive.asc
> sudo apt-key add ksplice-archive.asc
> ```

Comment: Good find, alas it doesn't seem to work. See my updated question.